# SQL find consecutive transactions within certain time period

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to find suspicious transactions that have 3 or more consecutive transactions within 10 minutes.

sample data

[image]

expected result

[image]

my below code doesn't work very well. coz it gives me the id 116 and 117, which is not right

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') is not null DROP TABLE #t;
create TABLE #t
(
 trans_id int,  trans_time  datetime,  store_address varchar(20)
)
insert into #t values
 (111, '5/27/18 6:36 AM', '79 street, NY')
,(112, '5/27/18 6:53 AM', '79 street, NY')
,(113, '5/27/18 6:54 AM', '79 street, NY')
,(114, '5/27/18 6:55 AM', '79 street, NY')
,(115, '5/27/18 6:59 AM', '79 street, NY')
,(116, '5/27/18 9:45 PM', '79 street, NY')
,(117, '5/27/18 9:47 PM', '79 street, NY')
,(118, '3/24/18 6:35 AM', '44 tree ave,FL')
,(119, '3/24/18 6:36 AM', '44 tree ave,FL')
,(120, '3/24/18 6:36 AM', '44 tree ave,FL')
,(121, '3/24/18 6:36 AM', '2 pop ave, NJ');
--select * from #t;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#self') is not null DROP TABLE #self;
SELECT DISTINCT d1.trans_id 'trans_id1',d2.trans_id 'trans_id2', d1.trans_time 't1',d2.trans_time 't2'
INTO #self
FROM #t d1 JOIN #t d2 ON d1.store_address = d2.store_address  --self join
AND DATEDIFF(minute,d1.trans_time,d2.trans_time) < 10
AND d1.trans_id <> d2.trans_id
AND d1.trans_id < d2.trans_id

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#date') is not null DROP TABLE #date;
SELECT DISTINCT d.trans_id,d.trans_time,d.store_address 
INTO #DATE 
FROM #t d
JOIN #SELF dd  ON d.trans_id=dd.trans_id1 or d.trans_id=dd.trans_id2   

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#address') is not null DROP TABLE #address;
SELECT store_address 
INTO #address --address for min count 3 of store address
FROM #t 
GROUP BY store_address HAVING COUNT(store_address) >= 3

SELECT * FROM #date d
JOIN #address a ON d.store_address = a.store_address
```

Comment: Please tell me why you did not include the rows with trans_id in (118, 119, 120)?

Comment: @AndreiOdegov you're right, 118,119,120 should be in the result, I have edited my screenshot

Comment: I thought so :) and took it into account in my answer.

Comment: I've got one more question. Suppose there are rows in the data with the following values ​​of the minute part of time during the same hour: `1, 20, 21, 29, 30`. Should we include two series of transactions in the result set: `20, 21, 29` and `21, 29, 30` or deal with this situation somehow else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gap and island problem, you can try to use `LAG` window function to get previous `trans_time` in the first `CTE` query.

then use `SUM` window function with `CASE WHEN` make row number by `datediff(minute, nextDt,trans_time)` greater than `10`.

Final only group `count` greater than 3 by `store_address` and `grp`.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, LAG(trans_time,1,trans_time) 
              OVER(PARTITION BY store_address ORDER BY trans_time) nextDt
FROM T
),CTE2 AS (
   SELECT *,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY grp,store_address) cnt
   FROM (
       SELECT *,SUM(CASE WHEN datediff(minute, nextDt,trans_time) >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
             OVER(PARTITION BY store_address ORDER BY trans_time) grp
      FROM CTE 
   ) t1
)
SELECT trans_id,trans_time,store_address    
FROM CTE2
WHERE cnt >= 3
ORDER BY trans_id
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a9ea06c85313b2f1c19f6fb051db1c89)

Comment: I'm sorry for last response, your answer is very solid and neat. you're good at math and logical thinking. Thanks for solving this classic problem.